# Recording from Line in jack

Tags: sound, alsa, jack

I have a usb audio card connected to my machine and I'm trying to record from "line in" but jackd seems to see it as a playback device even though I have it set as a capture device in alsa (see below)
anyone know how I can get jack to this "line in" as capture.
As you can see below jack sees only 2 capture device which equate to the 2 mic inputs on the card.  I was expecting to see 3 captures including the "line in"

```
#amixer -c1
    Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
      Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
      Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
      Limits: Playback 0 - 197
      Mono:
      Front Left: Playback 65 [33%] [-24.75dB] [on]
      Front Right: Playback 65 [33%] [-24.75dB] [on]
      Rear Left: Playback 90 [46%] [-20.06dB] [on]
      Rear Right: Playback 90 [46%] [-20.06dB] [on]
      Front Center: Playback 90 [46%] [-20.06dB] [on]
      Woofer: Playback 90 [46%] [-20.06dB] [on]
      Side Left: Playback 90 [46%] [-20.06dB] [on]
      Side Right: Playback 90 [46%] [-20.06dB] [on]
    Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
      Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
      Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
      Limits: Capture 0 - 6928
      Front Left: Capture 4161 [60%] [0.25dB] [on]
      Front Right: Capture 4096 [59%] [-0.01dB] [on]
    Simple mixer control 'PCM Capture Source',0
      Capabilities: enum
      Items: 'Mic' 'Line' 'IEC958 In' 'Mixer'
      Item0: 'Mic'
    Simple mixer control 'Line',0
      Capabilities: pvolume cvolume pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
      Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
      Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
      Limits: Playback 0 - 8065 Capture 0 - 6928
      Front Left: Playback 6204 [77%] [0.23dB] [off] Capture 4547 [66%] [1.76dB] [on]
      Front Right: Playback 6071 [75%] [-0.29dB] [off] Capture 4215 [61%] [0.46dB] [on]
    Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
      Capabilities: pvolume cvolume pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
      Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
      Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
      Limits: Playback 0 - 8065 Capture 0 - 6928
      Front Left: Playback 6144 [76%] [-0.01dB] [off] Capture 4096 [59%] [-0.01dB] [on]
      Front Right: Playback 6144 [76%] [-0.01dB] [off] Capture 4096 [59%] [-0.01dB] [on]
    Simple mixer control 'IEC958 In',0
      Capabilities: cswitch cswitch-joined
      Capture channels: Mono
      Mono: Capture [off]


#aplay -L
default:CARD=Device
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Device
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0
    USB Sound Device, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions

#jack_lsp
    system:capture_1
    system:capture_2
    system:playback_1
    system:playback_2
    system:playback_3
    system:playback_4
    system:playback_5
    system:playback_6
    system:playback_7
    system:playback_8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This card has a single stereo capture device.

This mixer control selects what is currently being captured through this device:

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM Capture Source',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Mic' 'Line' 'IEC958 In' 'Mixer'
  Item0: 'Mic'
```

Comment: `amixer -c1 sset "PCM Capture Source" "Line"`

Comment: Is it possible to set multiple devices for capture? If not is this just a sound card limitation

Comment: Try "Mixer", but then you also get all playback.